# this query does not run on my macbook but it runs on linux. What is the reason

Tags: mysql

Drop table student;
CREATE TABLE student(
    a int,
    b int,
    c varchar(100)
)ENGINE=INNODB;

Insert into student(a,b,c)
values(10,20,’sss’);

Comment: found the answer.. it looks like invisible garbage character insert

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the insert statement is the problem:

```
Insert into student(a,b,c) values(10,20,’sss’);
```

You are using some kind of curly quotes for the string literal `sss`.  Use single quotes and it should run everywhere:

```
INSERT INTO student(a,b,c) VALUES (10, 20, 'sss');
```